# Python PyQt6 QTableView first time selecting item with mouse in table, "selectedIndexes()" returns empty list

Tags: python, pyqt6

I am having an issue that I haven't been able to figure out.  When my table loads, selecting any first item and attempting to return it's index via `selectedIndexes()`, the index is empty.  If I then click anywhere else, the method works as intended.  Why?  Here's some MRC:

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import pyqtSignal, Qt
from PyQt6.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets as qt
import sys

class Main(qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        frame = qt.QFrame()
        self.setCentralWidget(frame)
        laymb = qt.QVBoxLayout(frame)
        model = QStandardItemModel()
        tabmb = TableViewClick()
        tabmb.setModel(model)
        tabmb.setGridStyle(Qt.PenStyle(0))
        tabmb.setSelectionMode(qt.QTableView.SelectionMode(1))
        tabmb.setSelectionBehavior(tabmb.SelectionBehavior(1))
        laymb.addWidget(tabmb)
        subj = []
        for e in range(10):
            subj.append(QStandardItem('Testing...'))
        model.appendColumn(subj)
        tabmb.signal.connect(self._click_table)

    def _click_table(self):
        table = self.sender()
        indexes = table.selectedIndexes()
        print(indexes)


class TableViewClick(qt.QTableView):
    signal = pyqtSignal()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.signal.emit()
        qt.QTableView.mousePressEvent(self, event)

app = qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
main_gui = Main()
main_gui.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

As you can see, I've tied it to a `mousePressEvent` because I need to call `_click_table` for later code.  I've troubleshot some and can select a row via `selectRow()`, and the above does not happen, but I don't want to do that because the GUI loads with a row already selected.  Any ideas how you can get the first time you click anywhere in the table to return the index?  With the index I'm going to get the row clicked for later code.  If there's a better way, I'm open to it.  But, I want to click an item and get the row.

Comment: Indexes get selected when you press the button, and this is achieved by the base implementation of `mousePressEvent()`: you're emitting the signal too early, at the point the view hasn't handled the button press, so no index has been selected yet. Move `self.signal.emit()` *after* `qt.QTableView.mousePressEvent(self, event)`.

Comment: That did it, @musicamante !  Rock out, baby.  Thanks a million.